# Relabel Prometheus metrics for a bunch of hosts behind a single load balancer target

Tags: prometheus

I have several hosts running `node_exporter`, all behind the same load balancer, and I'm trying to get metrics for each pulled into Prometheus.

The load balancer exposes the metrics for each host behind it like this:

- https://load-balancer.example.com/metrics?host=docker01
- https://load-balancer.example.com/metrics?host=docker02
- https://load-balancer.example.com/metrics?host=docker03

I can't seem to get the `relabel_config` quite right so that I get the same `job` for all 3, *different* `instance` labels for all 3, and the URL parameter passed through correctly.

This is what I'm trying right now:

`app_targets.json`

```
[
  {
    "targets": [
      "load-balancer.example.com:443/metrics?host=docker01",
      "load-balancer.example.com:443/metrics?host=docker02",
      "load-balancer.example.com:443/metrics?host=docker03"
    ]
  }
]
```

`prometheus.yml`

```
  - job_name: node_exporter_app_via_load_balancer
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
          - 'app_targets.json'
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]    # Set the path to just /metrics
        action: replace
        replacement: "/metrics"
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      - source_labels: [__address__]    # Set a ?host=docker0n URL parameter
        regex: 'host=(.*)'
        replacement: $1
        target_label: __param_host
      - source_labels: [__address__]    # Replace the "instance" label with "docker0n"
        regex: 'host=(.*)'
        replacement: $1
        target_label: instance
    scheme: 'https'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Everything I try I seem to either end up with *no* targets at all (???) or I end up with just a single target, with no URL parameter at all.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about [multi-target exporters](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/multi-target-exporter/).

In your case you could (and probably should) ditch name of the load balancer from your targets, and simply list them as `docker01`, `docker02`, etc.

Then use already familiar by blackbox exporter config:

```yaml
- job_name: node_exporter_app_via_load_balancer
  metrics_path: /metrics
  static_configs: 
    - targets:
      - docker01
      - docker02
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__address__]
      target_label: __param_host
    - source_labels: [__param_host]
      target_label: instance
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: load-balancer.example.com:443  # The your exporter’s real hostname:port.
```

Here, for simplicity sake I specified target in a `static_configs` block, but you of course can use `file_sd_configs` as before.